# create graph using macro

Tags: excel

1) Question

I want to use the macro for my raw data arrangement,
my raw data is in many .xls files in a folder, all in arrangement like bellow:

A1 ........ Blank
A(Blank) --------- Blank

I need to arrange each column in different sheets in 1 .xls file, like this

data (sheet1)             data (sheet2)          untill blank...
column A                    column B              untill blank...

2) Question is I need to loop this macro for easy to create graph... really appriciated the help

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+g

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\bukharms\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\analysis.crtx")

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Ambient").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$B$2:$B$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data (2)'!$B$2:$B$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='data (3)'!$B$2:$B$261"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='data (4)'!$B$2:$B$243"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "='data (5)'!$B$2:$B$265"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "='data (6)'!$B$2:$B$307"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "='data (7)'!$B$2:$B$728"

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\bukharms\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\analysis.crtx")

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Coolant Into Engine").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$C$2:$C$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data (2)'!$C$2:$C$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='data (3)'!$C$2:$C$261"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='data (4)'!$C$2:$C$243"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "='data (5)'!$C$2:$C$265"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "='data (6)'!$C$2:$C$307"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "='data (7)'!$C$2:$C$728"

 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\bukharms\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\analysis.crtx")

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Coolant Out from Engine").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$D$2:$D$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data (2)'!$D$2:$D$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='data (3)'!$D$2:$D$261"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='data (4)'!$D$2:$D$243"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "='data (5)'!$D$2:$D$265"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "='data (6)'!$D$2:$D$307"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "='data (7)'!$D$2:$D$728"
```

Comment: you can use the `.end` property of a range object to determine where the data ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through characters by converting ascii codes using Chr(). Chr(64) = 'A', Chr(65) = 'B' etc...

```
 For i = 1 To 4   
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$2:$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data (2)'!$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$2:$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$298"
    'etc...
  next i
```

Comment: The idea was to ceate chart which take series data from coloumn B2 to blank (no more input)

Comment: so instead of the For loop going from 1 to 4 make it go from 1 to Range(..).End(xlLeft).Column

Comment: where should i put it, is it here 

For i = 1 To 4 ---> change to 1 to Range(..).End(xlLeft).Column
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$2:$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$298"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data (2)'!$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$2:$" & Chr(i + 65) & "$298"
    'etc...
  next i